# Information on MySql database read/write access issues?

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection

When a *write/insert* operation is in process on **MySQL**, does it block *SELECT* operations from other programs?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Comment: Depends on your storage engine and transaction isolation level.